How to detect that GEE batch computation is full?
My colleagues and I we are concurrently launching many batch processes into the Google Earth Engine Python API.
They nicely piled up in the queue until one day:

How can we in an export script catch this error (and only this one, the other should continue to raise) and make our script to wait that rooms appear in the queue ?
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(
    image=band_4,
    description='imageToAssetExample',
    assetId='projects/your-project/assets/exampleExport',
    crs="EPSG:3857",
    region=geometry,
)

The solution could come from a error catching mechanism, but I don't know which error to catch:
try: 
    task.start()
except SomeEEException:
    sleep()

or counting them beforehand but I don't know how.
